# Record Matching - Efficient Iteration

Tags: java, performance, match

I have to preform record matching of 70K records in Java. One record size would be 200 bytes As record matching process all records compared against all records. My query is, how efficiently I can iterate and perform comparison.

Comment: That's only 14MB of data - pretty trivial. Where is the data coming from? What are your performance requirements? Have you tried implementing the simplest possible solution and proved that it's too slow?

Comment: This will give you n*(n-1)/2 iterations. Four your case that's 2'449'965'000. If your comparison is very quick this is ok. If not you will have a performance problem.

Comment: Put your data in a database and let your database handle it

Comment: You should describe your task, It probably is not neccessary to compare all 70K records to each other. using a suitable Index i asume that your task can be reduced to N * log N comparisons. But first you should check if the cheap brute force solution is fast enough

Comment: Thanks, the use case: we need to find out duplicate records. Based on certain matching equation which is (firstname AND lastname) AND (email OR phone). All names field matched exact, if not then fuzzy(distance, phonetic) match. Remaining field will have exact match. Data is in solr. Hope this would help. Is there any possibility to make it multithreaded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need compare all to each other. Once A - B is equal to B - A, you just need compare one with its successors. For example, you have { A, B, C, D }, then you compare A with B, C and D. Compare B with C and D, and compare C with D. This cut the amount of comparisons from n ^ 2 to n!.

You can optimize the algorithm by making search blocks. Put everyone with the same name and last name on the same block. Everyone with the same email on other block and so on. After all, you process each block comparing their records as described above. Depending on the amount of records you have, you will reduce dramatically the time of processing.

Answer (score -1):

Use Duke [https://github.com/larsga/Duke].
Not perfect, but it's free and Java.

We have .NET version that is better and faster, but it's in-house thing, not OSS yet.